"今だけは" does it have a particular meaning?
"ずっとこうしていたい、と思う。理由がなければ成立しない行為だけれど、それでも、今だけは。"
"i want to stay like this forever, I think. It would be something we wouldn't do without a reason, but still, only now"
What does 今だけは imply here? I understand the character is happy they can spend time with their crush but what does 今だけは mean? "only now..."?

You seem to have missed the nuance of "at least" suggested by the は.

それでも、今だけは。
Still, at least for now...

Something like 理由がある or こうしていられる is implied after this.
